# Rubymotion: Using a collectionView as a tabbar item

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I use a main view, with a TabBar on the bottom on the screen.
Each tab item should lead to a specific CollectionView (with a specific API call).

To be able to access the UICollectionViewController, it has to be initialised first.
So I used :

```
@main_controller = UITabBarController.alloc.init
layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.alloc.init
@main_controller.setViewControllers([
        GeolocScreen.alloc.init,
        ByNameController.alloc.initWithCollectionViewLayout(layout)
])
self.navigationController.pushViewController(@main_controller, animated:true)
```

That being said :

If not using a PM::Screen as a tab item, the tab icon and tab text does not show. That means, I have to click on the icon to display the icon / text in the tab bar

I then tried to call a PM::Screen instead of directly calling UICollectionViewController, and put it as a subview.
But I didn't manage to do it.

When, in my PM::Screen, I use

```
layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.alloc.init
ctrl = ByNameController.alloc.initWithCollectionViewLayout(layout)
append!(ctrl, :ctrl_style).get
```

I get

> Terminating app due
>        to uncaught exception 'NoMethodError', reason: 'subviews.rb:229:in create_view:: undefined method < for
>   ByNameController:0x1104fa050> (NoMethodError)

and when, in my PM::Screen I use

```
layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.alloc.init
screen = ByNameController.alloc.initWithCollectionViewLayout(layout)
view = UIView.alloc.init
view.append(screen.view)
```

clicking on the icon does nothing. I never enter viewWillAppear, which I guess is logical, since the controller is just appended... But my data is not loaded.

I must be missing something obvious, if you have an idea... Thanks !

PS: just in case; my controller

```
class ByNameController < UICollectionViewController
  attr_accessor :data

  COLLECTION_CELL_ID = "ArtCell"
  COLLECTION_HEADER_ID = "SectionHeader"

  def viewDidLoad
    super
    self.title = App.name

    rmq.stylesheet = CollectionStylesheet

    collectionView.tap do |cv|
      cv.registerClass(ArtCell, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: COLLECTION_CELL_ID)
      cv.delegate = self
      cv.dataSource = self
      cv.allowsSelection = true
      cv.allowsMultipleSelection = false
      rmq(cv).apply_style :collection_view
    end
reload_data
  end
  def reload_data
    mp "RELAODING DATA "
    Api.shared.url ".........json"
    Api.shared.file_name "content.json"
   Api.shared.download_data

  end
def viewWillDisappear(animated)
    App.notification_center.unobserve @reload_observer
  end

def viewWillAppear(animated)
    super
    @reload_observer = App.notification_center.observe 'ReloadDataNotification' do |notification|
      self.data = Api.shared.hash
      self.collectionView.reloadData
    end
  end

  def collectionView(view, numberOfItemsInSection: section)
    self.data.nil? ? 0 : self.data["items"].reject{|i| i['name'] == "" }.count
  end

  def collectionView(view, cellForItemAtIndexPath: index_path)
    view.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(COLLECTION_CELL_ID, forIndexPath: index_path).tap do |cell|
      rmq.build(cell) unless cell.reused
      art = {
        art: self.data["items"][index_path.row]["art"],
        name: self.data["items"][index_path.row]["name"],
        thumb: self.data["items"][index_path.row]["thumb"]
      }
      cell.art = art
    end
  end

  def collectionView(view, didSelectItemAtIndexPath: index_path)
    selected = self.data["items"][index_path.row]
    @store = StoreInfoController.alloc.init
    @store.store_id = selected["storeID"]
    self.navigationController.pushViewController(@store, animated:true)
  end

  end
```

Answer (score 0):

To customize the tab bar item for your UIViewController, use the tabBarItem property:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/tabBarItem

PM::Screen does not have anything to do here. It is simply a subclass of UIViewController the same way UICollectionViewController is.